# C# :Unity container and ILogger

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I'm working on ASP .Net MVC5 project, I'm using ILogger interface inder ***Microsoft.Extensions.Logging*** and Unity framework for **DI**.

What I want is to inject **ILogger** into my project to use it in my controllers.

I installed Unity and Unity.MVC nuget packages in my project and I tried to inject ILogger like this  :

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>), (new HierarchicalLifetimeManager()));
        }
```

My controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("TEST log event message");

            return View();
        }
```

Always when I run the project I get this error :

[image: Project exception error]

Comment: You only registered the generic version of `ILogger<>` while your controller is expecting the non-generic version. Did you try to simply register `Logger` as `ILogger`?

Answer (score 3):

You registered `ILogger<T>` but your `HomeController` expects `ILogger`.
Unity container is trying to build an `ILogger`; it is an interface so it has no public ctor.

Change your `HomeController` ctor to this to make your registrations work...

```
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
```